# Can't send data form angularjs to php service

Tags: php, api, angularjs, slim

I want to create crud app from angular js and php

I use slim framework for route api

This is my code https://gist.github.com/lifez/7212525

I try to debug my code with console.log it show json data but can't insert to mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your php code from:

```
function addUser() {
      $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

to:

```
function addUser() {
      $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
      $user = json_decode($request->getBody());
```

just like in your test() method.

Comment: I tired it but can't insert to mysql

how can i debug $user